# Payment schedule based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
names = ['john', 'pete', 'jack']
funds = [1000, 3600, 2390]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names, 'Fund': funds})

df['m1'] = np.nan
df['m2'] = np.nan
df['m3'] = np.nan
df['m4'] = np.nan
df['m5'] = np.nan
df['m6'] = np.nan
df['m7'] = np.nan
df['m8'] = np.nan
df['m9'] = np.nan
df['m10'] = np.nan
df['m11'] = np.nan
df['m12'] = np.nan
```

**original df**

```
   Name  Fund  m1   m2   m3   m4   m5   m6   m7   m8   m9  m10  m11  m12  
0  john  1000 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                           
1  pete  3600 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       
2  jack  2390 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The recreated `df` structure represents the structure of a typical csv file which I receive. I am required to populate based on a set of 'release of fund conditions' which vary from csv table to the next.

Below I have provided an example of a set of 'release of fund conditions' for which I would like to create a script that I can easily adapt when the conditions are changed.

**Release of fund conditions**

**john** 10% of fund monthly for 10 months starting after m1

**pete** 12.5% of fund monthly for 8 months starting after m2

**jack** 20% of fund monthly for 5 months starting after m4

I want to be able to apply the *Release of fund conditions* as code to produce the output shown below:

**Desired Output**

```
   Name  Fund  m1   m2   m3   m4   m5   m6   m7   m8   m9  m10  m11  m12  
0  john  1000 NaN  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  NaN                           
1  pete  3600 NaN  NaN  450  450  450  450  450  450  450  450  NaN  NaN       
2  jack  2390 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  478  478  478  478  478  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I think maybe a tuple or dictionary might be needed, but honestly I do not know how to tackle this task.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So what is actually that you want to do?

Comment: I am looking for help to write code that will replicates the 'release of fund conditions' logic and outputs the final df as shown

Comment: This is just a pattern solving problem and not a real life problem scenario. You just have to read the pattern. Hint: See the id and indices of columns and create a relation and the values are just (funds/no of months) as per pattern which you can calculate also using the relation you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this snippet as a starting point -

```
# target columns range for each Name 
cols = list(df.columns)
john = cols[cols.index('m2'):cols.index('m2')+10]
pete = cols[cols.index('m3'):cols.index('m3')+8]
jack = cols[cols.index('m5'):cols.index('m5')+5]

# Calculate funds for each Name and distribute in the targeted columns
df.loc[df.Name=='john', john] = [df[df.Name=='john'].iloc[0].Fund*0.1] * len(john)
df.loc[df.Name=='pete', pete] = [df[df.Name=='pete'].iloc[0].Fund*0.125] * len(pete)
df.loc[df.Name=='jack', jack] = [df[df.Name=='jack'].iloc[0].Fund*0.20] * len(jack)
```

This is a basic `pandas` logic of row indexer and column indexer to assign a list of values. The first section of the snippet targets the column names according to your logic. For example, targeted column names for john start from `m2` and continue to the next 10 months.

`cols[cols.index('m2'):cols.index('m2')+10]` returns these column lists where `10` is number of next months. This list of columns has been used to target columns in `df` for `john` to update values.

The same logic has been applied to other `Name`s too.

Comment: Yes, I have tried some swapping out of the conditions and using variables for target columns and it works perfectly first time. thank you immensely